# Diophantine equation Oeis A159589

Tags: diophantine-equations

Considera the diophantine equation:

$y^2=x^2+(x+449)^2$.

Is there a method to solve this equation?

And why an Oeis sequence Is dedicated to this equation? Has this diophantine equation something special, has this diophantine equation some context?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A159589 gives a recurrence for $a(n)$ - so, yes, this looks like the full solution.

Comment: @Twiga Welcome to MathOverflow. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24y%5E2%3Dx%5E2%2B(x%2B449)%5E2%24&p=1), the Math SE site's [Can OEIS be used for searching of sequences of pairs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1999497) has an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1999515) that states "... the solutions $(x,y)$ of $x^2+(x+31)^2=y^2$ are [A118674](https://oeis.org/A118674), [A157646](https://oeis.org/A157646)". Thus, there is at least one other similar Diophantine equation in OEIS, but there's also no reason given for why it's there.

Comment: @Twiga As for solving it, $449$ is prime so there are $2$ basic cases. With $\gcd(x,449)=d$, then if $d=1$, we can leave your equation alone, else $d=449$ so we can set $x=449a$ & $y=449b$ to get $b^2=a^2+(a+1)^2$. Then we're trying to find primitive [Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple), using the formula provided there, but also handling the possibility that $x$ and/or $x+449$ are negative. Solving the equations will then result in a [generalized Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Generalized_Pell's_equation).